# Create JavaClass that loads the ontology and displays all the Persons (without using queries, without inference)

Tags: java, sparql, jena

I am stuck on creating a function in java allowing to display all the Personns of an OWL file with Jena.

More precisely, I have an ontology where I have a Personal class and I would like in java and using Jena, display all the Personns. (Without using queries, and without inference)

I have tried several codes but nothing works.

If someone can help me please

```java
public static void main (String [] args) {    
    Model model = JenaEngine.readModel ("data / movie.owl");
    String NS = "";
    NS = model.getNsPrefixURI ("");
    
    //JenaEngine.readDataType(model, NS, movie, "Year");
    
    JenaEngine.readObjectType (model, NS, "Personn", "name");
}
```

Comment: it's useless to show your custom function calls instead of what native Jena code is behind those methods like `readObjectTyoe`. Also, you're using some old non official [Github project](https://github.com/xiaoque/Jena-project-with-ontology/blob/master/km/src/tools/JenaEngine.java) - but this is not the official Jena API, it just wraps some code of it. Clearly, nobody here is familiar with it. Moreover, it's 6 years old and still using Jena 2.x - we have nowadays Jena 3.16.0

Comment: That said, the official docs already contain everything you need, you just have to read it: https://jena.apache.org/documentation/ontology/

Comment: About your code example, `"Personn"` does clearly contain a typo unless your class is really called "Personn" which would be weird